# ls: reading directory ................': Input/output error

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, ssd

I have my local NAS on the base of Cubietruck (Ubuntu Xenial with Armbian Linux 3.4.113-sun7i) with smbd for samba shares. As storage extension I use 2 TB Western Digital SSD connected via USB and automatically mounted on startup with fstab on /mnt/wd1:

```
UUID=0e32bef4-78a1-4172-bc7d-de2d74f9b092       /mnt/wd1        ext4    defaults,noatime,nodiratime,commit=600,errors=remount-ro,x-gvfs-hide    0       1
```

There are 2 folders on this SSD with owner for samba user and with appropriate permissions:

```
root@Artisan:~# ls -la /mnt/wd1
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 artisan artisan 4096 Nov 22 19:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 Nov 22 19:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 artisan artisan 4096 Nov 22 19:36 Other
drwxrwxr-x 3 artisan artisan 4096 Dec 12 11:44 Video
```

Here's part of smb.conf

```
security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam
unix charset = utf-8
dos charset = cp932

[Music]
path = /ncsdata/Music
comment = Music
read only = no
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
create mode = 0775
directory mode = 0775
valid users = artisan
force user = artisan
guest ok = no

[Video]
path = /mnt/wd1/Video
comment = Video
read only = no
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
create mode = 0775
directory mode = 0775
valid users = artisan
force user = artisan
guest ok = no
```

"Music" is located on local Cubietruck storage and works perfectly for read/write. "Video" is located on mounted SSD and allows reading, but writing  from windows laptop ends in undefined time (seconds to minutes) or allows to completely write file and stops on the next file with error "There is a problem accessing //ARTISAN/Video". After all I can't access it even from root account:

```
root@Artisan:~# ls -la /mnt/wd1/Video
ls: reading directory '/mnt/wd1/Video': Input/output error
```

SSD stays mounted:

```
root@Artisan:/mnt/wd1# df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev               955288         0     955288   0% /dev
tmpfs              201412      3556     197856   2% /run
/dev/sda1       922976468 674280112  201811784  77% /
tmpfs             1007056       140    1006916   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             1007056         0    1007056   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             1007056       108    1006948   1% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p1    7529608   3235512    4189700  44% /media/mmcboot
/dev/sdb1      1968975652   1964664 1866992812   1% /mnt/wd1
armbian-ramlog      51200       344      50856   1% /var/log
tmpfs              201412         8     201404   1% /run/user/1000
overlaid           201412         8     201404   1% /run/user/1000/ncadmin-chromium
tmpfs              201412         0     201412   0% /run/user/0
```

After reboot the mount is accessible again. What could be a problem?

UPD: After some time mount is actually gone:

```
root@Artisan:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              955288         0    955288   0% /dev
tmpfs             201412      3560    197852   2% /run
/dev/sda1      922976468 674248620 201843276  77% /
tmpfs            1007056       140   1006916   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1007056         0   1007056   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1007056       108   1006948   1% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p1   7529608   3235512   4189700  44% /media/mmcboot
armbian-ramlog     51200      7220     43980  15% /var/log
tmpfs             201412         8    201404   1% /run/user/1000
overlaid          201412         8    201404   1% /run/user/1000/ncadmin-chromium
tmpfs             201412         0    201412   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `ls -la /mnt/wd1/`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro is correct. The command as it written would be looking for `/mnt/wd1/mnt/wd1` which is probably not what you want

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This won't resolve the problem nevertheless. The situation is the same, error is other: root@Artisan:~# ls -la /mnt/wd1/Video
ls: reading directory '/mnt/wd1/Video': Input/output error. I've edited my initial question to not confuse others.

Comment: Seems like your NFS got stuck. Try a lazy unmount on it.  `umount -l <drive>`. Mount it back in and try to use it. If it works, your windows might be the culprit, keeping the drive busy until it sort of times out. This one will not be easy to fix, even unfixable maybe. There are a lot of reasons why Windows would "break" a share. Could be the charset, file type, even the speed..... hard to tell.

Comment: After some time the mount wasn't actually listed anymore.

Comment: It's also 2 TB SSD (not 1 TB as I stated initially) if this matters. Sorry, trying to make few thing parallel and miss some details :(

Comment: Perhaps silly question but did you run `fsck` on drive to check integrity?

Comment: Yup, nothing suspicious as for me: root@Artisan:~# fsck -f /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
/lost+found not found.  Create<y>? yes
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

wd1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
wd1: 22/125026304 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 9837012/500090880 blocks

Comment: Strange, but it seems to work now. 3 hours of transfer ok so far. Thanks, WinEunuuchs2Unix!